# Windres: Resource compilation error if there are spaces in the path

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, ninja, windres

The mingw+qt6+cmake+ninja project depends on the library, which, according to the standard, is installed in 'C:\Program Files\somelib'. There is no way to change the installation path

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(untitled_qt6 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
qt_standard_project_setup()

include_directories("C:/Program Files/somelib/include")
find_library(SOMELIB NAMES somelib PATHS "C:/Program Files/somelib/lib" REQUIRED NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH)

set(app_icon_resource_windows "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/icon.rc")

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        ${app_icon_resource_windows}
)

qt_add_executable(untitled_qt6
    MANUAL_FINALIZATION
    ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
)

target_link_libraries(untitled_qt6 PRIVATE
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets
    ${SOMELIB}
)

set_target_properties(untitled_qt6 PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)

qt_finalize_executable(untitled_qt6)
```

There is a known error with the transmission of the path

```
cc1.exe: fatal error: Files/somelib: No such file or directory
```

which can be solved by passing the path as follows.

```
windres -I\""C:/Program Files/somelib/include\""
```

Is there any way to interfere with the build process or solve this problem in another way without changing the path to the library?

Comment: You could use the short name. `dir /X` will show it to you, probably `PROGRA~1`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja If I add a short path to `include_directories()`, then the path to the library header files will not be defined. And I get `somelibh.h: No such file or directory`
As an example `include_directories("C:/PROGRA~1/IVIFOU~1/VISA/WinNT/Include")`